# How to make one line

Tags: qgis, symbology, line

[image]

I have drawn two forks. After drawing, I put the two lines together, but it looks like the picture is divided into two lines.

[image]

I want to draw a line that connects like the picture above.

Comment: what tool did you run ?

Comment: Please provide more details on what exactly you did, because "I put the two lines together" tells us nothing.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click <kbd>Advanced</kbd> in the layer Symbology pane and choose `Symbol levels...`

[image]

2. Check `Enable symbol levels`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at YouTube and found the answer myself.

*edited

1. shape file layer > right click > Properties
2. Symbology > (plus button) add symbol layer
3. Make a bold line (Modify stroke style), color: black, cap style: round
4. black line layer move down

like this

-Line

ㅡsimple line

ㅡsimple line(bold line)

And...
Save it from a pop-up window(Save New Symbol) so you can apply the settings immediately later.

I'm sorry I didn't write a proper comment because I've never used it before.

Comment: Link-only answers are vulnerable to link rot. You should always include a real answer that hits the highlights of the linked material, or it's possible the answer will be deleted.